# Upper bound of smallest eigenvalue of a structure tensor matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I wish to know if there are any good upper bounds that exist for the smallest eigen value of a [structure tensor matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_tensor). I ask this because I need to lower bound the spectral norm of the pseudo inverse of a matrix. 
Also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23171991/what-does-eigen-value-of-structure-tensor-matrix-denote) has a good description of this matrix.

Thanks